# Mailchimp embedded form Integration to Django application Error

Tags: python, html, css, django, mailchimp

**Situation**

- I have created a Mailchimp email list form with the official mailchimp embedded form creator.
- When I test it on my development machine it works a couple of times but after a while like a day later it does not when I pus the code online to my digital ocean server it just stop working immediately.
- I have not modified the code that I have copied and pasted from mailchimp in any ways.

**Correct working case**

1. people type in their email in to a filed
2. click subscribe
3. Pop up windows comes up from mailchimp
4. recaptcha does on that pop up window
5. Approval shows on the small op up window
6. Subscriber receives conformational mail
7. If I go online I can see that there is that email that added to my audience

**ERROR case**

1. people type in their email in to a filed
2. click subscribe
3. Reloaded the same page I was on with a long URl like this

```
https://MYWEBSITE.COM/?EMAIL=SUBSCRIBER%40gmail.com&b_11111111111111111111111111111111_1111111111111111=&subscribe=Subscribe
```

4. No email address added to my audience

**Mailchimp Code**

```
<!-- Begin Mailchimp Signup Form -->
<link href="//cdn-images.mailchimp.com/embedcode/horizontal-slim-10_7.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<style type="text/css">
    #mc_embed_signup{background:#fff; clear:left; font:14px Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; width:100%;}
    /* Add your own Mailchimp form style overrides in your site stylesheet or in this style block.
       We recommend moving this block and the preceding CSS link to the HEAD of your HTML file. */
</style>
<style type="text/css">
    #mc-embedded-subscribe-form input[type=checkbox]{display: inline; width: auto;margin-right: 10px;}
    #mergeRow-gdpr {margin-top: 20px;}
    #mergeRow-gdpr fieldset label {font-weight: normal;}
    #mc-embedded-subscribe-form .mc_fieldset{border:none;min-height: 0px;padding-bottom:0px;}
</style>


<div id="mc_embed_signup">
<form action="https://MYPERSONALPROJECTNAME.us19.list-manage.com/subscribe/post?u=1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111" method="post" id="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" name="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" class="validate" target="_blank" novalidate>
    <div id="mc_embed_signup_scroll">

    <input type="email" value="" name="EMAIL" class="email" id="mce-EMAIL" placeholder="email address" required>
    <!-- real people should not fill this in and expect good things - do not remove this or risk form bot signups-->
    <div style="position: absolute; left: -5000px;" aria-hidden="true">
      <input type="text" name="1111111111111111111111111111111111111111" tabindex="-1" value="">
    </div>
    <div class="clear">
      <input type="submit" value="Subscribe" name="subscribe" id="mc-embedded-subscribe" class="button"> 
    </div>
    </div>
</form>
</div>

<!--End mc_embed_signup-->
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. I have cleaned up the multiple containers that were holding the mailchimp code.
2. `<div class="container text-center">` was not closed so I have closed that with `</div>`
3. Go thru the settings of mailchimp and validate email address you want to use for sending.
4. On server:

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo systemctl restart gunicorn
```